# Call two UIGestureRecognizer at the same time

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Here's the question: I have an UIScrollView with an UIButton as a subView. Both the UIScrollView and the UIButton have an UILongPressGestureRecognizer assigned to them. Is it possible that if the UILongPressGestureRecognizer of the UIButton is called the one of the UIScrollView gets called too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to manually call the long-press handling function for your scrollview when the button is long-pressed. You shouldn't try and run more than one thing on your interface at the same time, because interface code needs to be executed only on the main thread.